# Internal server error trying to overwrite response host name using ARR IIS module

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I have atlassian jira version 5 bug tracker server in my private network with domain name bt01.private.com. I want to publish this server to internet using application request routing iis module. I setup a new server with iis 8 and arr 2.5 on windows server 2012 platform, this server is connected to both private and public networks. Then I created a web site, set binding to jira01.my-public-domain.com, and set request redirect to bt01 in my private network. From the first look everything works fine, but sometimes jira generates links which include domain name (for example http://bt01.private.com/issue/42). I want to rewrite response host names using arr outbound rule, but, when I try to create this rule, server starts to return 500 error. I also checked the same trick for atlassian confluence and obtained the same results.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are the details of the 500 error?

Comment: The details are: 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: That sounds like the generic error message you're seeing in the browser.  You should be able to find the real details in the Application event log on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved using atlassian documentation. All details are here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Integrating+JIRA+with+IIS+using+ARR